# How to migrate Notes mail agents to Microsoft Exchange (i.c. Office365)?

Tags: email, exchange-server, lotus-notes, office365, agents

A client insists on moving from Notes/Domino to Office365 (no further comments on that please). There are some mail agents that provide automated functionality. In one case, it is an agent in a mail database that, when it receives a mail, it responds with a mail that contains a unique reference for the mail just received. It's their way to generate unique mail references.

How to create an alternative solution, in Office 365? Can one develop an agent in Office365?
If it must be an equivalent solution, does it have to be an Outlook client that's always on?

Or are there other ways to generate reply mails from a special mail account?
Can one send a mail to an SQL server, for instance?

I'm open to all your suggestions! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do some research into what's currently available for Office365 users via Exchange Web Services - or better yet, the Exchange Web Services Managed API.

Assuming that you Office365 gives you full access through Exchange Web Services, you can write code to use the [subscription/notification services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx) for the mailboxes that you want to monitor, and then have your code send the emails.

There may also be better ways.